# is it possibile extract a fixed format string form a long string in spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

i am trying to extract a fixed format string from a column,
this column contains multiple fixed format string.

e.g.

2018-1234567,2018-0123456,2018-2345678

but it always contain many kinds of garbage strings(casue this column input manually)

e.g.

SN:2018-1234567 and 2018-0123456 and 2018-2345678

or

tracking ID:2018-1234567; 2018-0123456;2018-2345678

i can use RXREPLACE function to elimated some of them but i can not remove some unpredicted garbage string in the future.

so i am wondering, is there a function can just extract fixed format strings from this column? the fixed format string is YYYY-NNNNNNN (year-7digit number)

if i can do this, i needn't worry about the furture unknown garbage string in this column.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be a cast-iron solution however it works for the examples, without cryptic look-arounds, if you are happy to have a space as the separator:

```
Trim(RXReplace([mystring],"\\\D*\\\d*\\\D*(\\\d{4}-\\\d{7})","$1,","g"))
```

It captures the string you like (\\d{4}-\\d{7}) and replaces it with itself $1 followed by a space. Everything that is not surrounded by () is left behind. It assumes that whatever 'garbage' appears before/between each string is made of a mixture of digits (\\d) and non-digits (\\D).

In fact simply \\D* would have worked, but it would not have removed something like tracking**123** ID:

The `Trim()` is to remove the last space.

Gaia

Comment: sorry typo: "$1," should be "$1 " (i.e. space not comma)

Comment: It works with two back slashes, gives an error with three, so I don't agree with the edits